# NullPointerException when accessing binding in Fragment after receiving JSON results

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm having a problem with accessing the binding in my SearchAllFragment. It's returning a NullPointerException.

Here's the flow:

SearchActivity: When an intent with ACTION_SEARCH is detected, I perform a search using the doMySearch method

```java
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            doMySearch(query);
    }
}

private void doMySearch(String query) {
        URLHelper.request(Request.Method.GET, url, params, jsonElement -> {
            JsonArray contactsArray = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("contacts");
            if (contactsArray.size() > 0) {
                runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    searchAllFragment = SearchAllFragment.newInstance();
                    SearchActivity.this.jsonResults = searchAllFragment;
                    jsonResults.SearchResultsArray(contactsArray);
                });
}
```

Interface: I'm using an interface SearchJsonResults to communicate between the activity and the fragment:

```java
interface SearchJsonResults {
    void SearchResultsElement(JsonElement jsonElement);
    void SearchResultsArray(JsonArray jsonArray);
}
```

SearchAllFragment: The fragment implements the above interface. When SearchResultsArray method is called, I attempt to access binding which is throwing a NullPointerException.

```java
public class SearchAllFragment extends Fragment  implements  SearchActivity.SearchJsonResults{
    private FragmentSearchAllBinding binding;

    public SearchAllFragment() {}

    public static SearchAllFragment newInstance() {
        return new SearchAllFragment();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentSearchAllBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void SearchResultsElement(JsonElement jsonElement) {

    }

    @Override
    public void SearchResultsArray(JsonArray jsonArray) {
        binding.rvContacts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        SearchAdapter searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(new SearchDiff());
        binding.rvContacts.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(requireContext()));
        binding.rvContacts.setAdapter(searchAdapter);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type userListType = new TypeToken<List<SearchContactsModel>>(){}.getType();
        List<SearchContactsModel> users = gson.fromJson(jsonArray.toString(), userListType);
        searchAdapter.submitList(users);
    }
```

The problem: binding in the SearchAllFragment in SearchResultsArray is null.

What am I missing here? How can I prevent the binding from being null?

Comment: Did the fragment view created when you call SearchResultsArray; it seems that not.

Comment: i also thing it's not, the question is why?,when i call SearchResultsArray i am creating a newInstance, and if the onCreateView got called before, why should binding get null?, when i am not setting it anywhere to null!

Comment: and what else cam i do for it?

Comment: `when i call SearchResultsArray i am creating a newInstance` which type of that instance you mean? the fragment?

Comment: yes 
    public static SearchAllFragment newInstance() {
        return new SearchAllFragment();
    }

Comment: This creates a fragment class, but doesn't put it into the fragment manager to be shown and kick off its lifecycle

Comment: how can i put it into the fragment manager to be shown?

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/transactions#java

Comment: but it looks to me that i am able to use it if i make a FragmentTransaction.replace, but not with view pager